# can we mix global import of all components in bootstrap-vue with import of selected component?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I want to significantly reduce tag noise and reduce long tag names to short names in bootstrap-vue. This is what I did in vue-cli generated project in main.js:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'
import bformGroup from 'bootstrap-vue/es/components/form-group/form-group'
import bformInput from 'bootstrap-vue/es/components/form-input/form-input'
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'

Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.component('bfg', bformGroup) // b-form-group
Vue.component('bfin', bformInput) // b-form-input
```

In MyComponent.Vue now I have:

```
<bfg id="exampleInputGroup2" label="Your Name:" label-for="exampleInput2">
      <bfin id="exampleInput2" type="text" v-model="form.name" required placeholder="Enter name">
      </bfin>
</bfg>
```

Instead of:

```
<b-form-group id="exampleInputGroup2" label="Your Name:" label-for="exampleInput2">
      <b-form-input id="exampleInput2" type="text" v-model="form.name" required placeholder="Enter name">
      </b-form-input>
</b-form-group>
```

Is this technically correct? In very large forms it makes a huge difference and makes the form looks much cleaner and focused on key content of the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Vue.use(BootstrapVue)` registers all the components and directives globally with their default long tag name.

When you do

```
Vue.component('bfg', bformGroup) // b-form-group 
Vue.component('bfin', bformInput) // b-form-input
```

You are registering the components again but with a different tag name. So there are two copies of the same component.

Either use `Vue.use(BootstrapVue)` to globally register all the components or manually import the component you want and register it as you are doing with a different tag name if you do not want two copies

See [Individual components and directives](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/#individual-components-and-directives)

Comment: Vamsi I checked I can use both original long form and my short form of the same component at the same time. Having two copies of the same component can result in bugs? I only need a few components to be individually imported while vast majority I want to use original tag names.

Comment: @ace yup you can use the both at once. There will be no bugs...AFAIK. but you will have two copies